# How can I fix 'Invalid key' error & retrieve JSON data of specific places from Maps API?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-markers, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

So I am trying to use the Places API for an android app. I've used the correct URL to query for the JSON results of places however when I run the app I receive this error in my logcat: `data: {   "error_message": "The provided API key is invalid.",   "html_attributions" : [],   "results" : [],   "status": "REQUEST_DENIED"}`.

When I used Maps API to show current coordinates on the map it worked but now that I want it to mark specific locations of restrarunts on a map using the Places API I get an error.

My developer console has Places API & Maps SKD for android enabled. Application restrictions are set to android apps with the correct package name & fingerprint provided. API restrictions are set to 'Don't restrict key'. My API key in my code is also correct.

I've spent a lot of time researching a solution but cannot seem to find one that works. I've used a second API key with restrictions turned off, I've checked that all the APIS that I need are enabled in my developer console.

Here is the error message I receive at run time:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.project.prayerpal, sha256=[29a99a0744d90545fc8c9b9a2572fc89423676bbd3ff074ea76faa7ff], atk=false, ver=230617044.true (go/gsrlt)
    at ajp.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230617044@23.06.17 (190400-0):3)
    at ajp.get(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230617044@23.06.17 (190400-0):2)
    at akz.g(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230617044@23.06.17 (190400-0):2)
    at yr.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230617044@23.06.17 (190400-0):1)
    at yt.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230617044@23.06.17 (190400-0):0)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:463)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.project.prayerpal, sha256=[29a99a0744d90545fc8c9b9a2572fc89423676bbd3ff074ea76faa7ff], atk=false, ver=230617044.true (go/gsrlt)
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2441)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2425)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2408)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2350)
    at ff.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230617044@23.06.17 (190400-0):2)
    at ru.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230617044@23.06.17 (190400-0):4)
    at jl.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230617044@23.06.17 (190400-0):2)
    at kk.t(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230617044@23.06.17 (190400-0):2)
    at kk.u(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230617044@23.06.17 (190400-0):3)
    at kk.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230617044@23.06.17 (190400-0):2)
    at ko.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@230617044@23.06.17 (190400-0):69)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Here is the code that uses the URL:

```
public StringBuilder queryString(){

    double Latitude = 48.8566;
    double Longitude = 2.3522;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    sb.append("location=" + Latitude + "," + Longitude);
    sb.append("&radius=5000");
    sb.append("&types=" + "restraurant");
    sb.append("&sensor=true");
    sb.append("&key=" + R.string.API_key);

    return sb;
}
```

Here is the code that gets the data from the URL:

```
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{

    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.connect();

        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){

            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();
    }catch (Exception e){

        Log.d("error", "downloading url failed");
    }finally {

        assert iStream != null;
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: From what I can see, you're trying to use the server side Places API on your client side. Is that correct? Maybe you could try the [Places SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk)

Comment: @Yrll could you elaborate on this please. I am using the places API that I found on the developers console but how can I use the places SDK for android?

Comment: Places API is used for server side requests, it is not supposed to be used on the client side. For you to be able to use Places API on your android app, you can use the SDK that Google Maps already provided for you. I already included the link on my comment before. But here's also the link to the tutorial on their documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/autocomplete-tutorial